# save json data from a localhost webservice with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have json data in the format of the following:

```
{ "david" :12, "john": "21", "kevin": [{"address":"friendly"}]}}
```

this data is saved in my localhost web, in the URL : `localhost8080/example/search?data=1`

I want to use javascript/jQuery to save this data in a variable, and then parse the information i need later, I looked up for some ways to do this, I found the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'localhost8080/example/search?data=1', 
        data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
        success: function (data) { 
            var names = data
            $('#a_div').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

What is the line `data: { get_param: 'value' }`  doing? I dont want to get certain data, i want to save the entire json data and save it as a var like the following:

```
var example1 = { "david" :12, "john": "21", "kevin": [{"address":"friendly"}]}}
```

as my result. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your JSON is invalid, it has a `}` at the end that should not be there.

```
data: { get_param: 'value' },
```

This is passing the POST data named `get_param` with value `value`. If you don't need to pass the data to the request you can safely remove it.

```
var dataSaved;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'localhost8080/example/search?data=1',
        success: function (data) { 
            dataSaved = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#a_div').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

By doing this you will save the data retrieved with the request to the `dataSaved` variable which will be an object obtained by parsing the JSON via `JSON.parse`. Then you can reuse it whenever you want.

Comment: since i dont need it, data: { get_param: 'value' },  can be removed ? You kept it in in your code.

Comment: Yes. As I said, you can safely remove it. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

First off, take a good look at jQuery's ajax function, specifically the data attribute ([here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).
The `get_param` is referring to the GET request, not to the verb of receiving.

To answer you question I'll split the answer to two options I see currently:

1) **To save the data in a databse.**
(Assuming you're using php)
I would rewrite the ajax as follows:

```
var exampleJSON = { "david" :12, "john": "21", "kevin": [{"address":"friendly"}]}}    
$.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'localhost8080/example/saveData.php', // You need to create this page
            data: { data: exampleJSON }, 
            success: function (data) { 
                alert("Completed saving data")
            }
        });
```

Then in `saveData.php`
You can get the data sent by jQuery using: `$_POST['data']`
You will then process the information as you wish (inserting to a databse, cookie etc...)

2) **To save via local-storage:** 
(Note: this will not work with old browsers)
Read:
[Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

The data property does not specify which data you get from the server, it specifies the query parameters which get appended to the url you're accessing (for a GET anyway). (see [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

You can use either:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'localhost:8080/example/search?data=1',
    success: function (data) { ... }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'localhost:8080/example/search',
    data: {data: 1},
    success: function (data) { ... }
});
```

These will both result in a request to *localhost:8080/example/search?data=1*.

Since you want to save JSON data in a variable, you might consider using jQuery.getJSON() (see [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)).